# Not able to redirect in community builder

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning, community-builder

I am trying to load a create a tab in community builder which when clicked load's a VF page which performs some computations and then redirects to another page (managed package) but when I try to view test this functionality in build preview it works but it does not work when viewing published community and not loading and page when clicked on tab.

Comment: What is the way you are using to redirect ?

Comment: I am calling a controller's function which gives me the page reference to the page I am redirecting.